# Why is Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 different from Ubuntu 17.04 + GNOME 3.24

Tags: gnome

What is the difference between Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 ([Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 Released and What’s Next | ubuntugnome.org](https://ubuntugnome.org/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-released/)) and Ubuntu 17.04 + GNOME 3.24.

If installed side by side, they are definitely different. The boot screen and login screen have differences, there are Wifi issues (seemingly packet loss, can't access Ubuntu.com servers at all), Bluetooth mouse connectivity issues, general subtle UI differences, etc...

But there is no explanation, anywhere that I can find, that states they are in fact separate. So which one is official? Why do they go by the same name but are actually different?